# Distribution of the sum of $m$ inverse exponential random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $T_1, \ldots, T_m$ be $m$ random variables with $T_i \sim \exp(\lambda_T)$. We are interested in the sum

$$
T' = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{T_i}
$$

which is itself a random variable. By definition, each term in the sum follows an inverse exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda_T$. However, I have found no literature covering the distribution of a sum such as this one. I have two questions:

$a.$ Can one derive the distribution of $T'$ analytically? If so, how?

$b.$ Is there any literature covering the sum of inverse exponential random variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse exponential variable $Y_i = 1/T_i$ has a Fréchet distribution with PDF
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda/y}}{y^2}, \quad y > 0.$$
However, the sum of iid $Y_i$ does not have an elementary closed form, since even the case $n = 2$ requires the evaluation of
$$f_{T'} (t) = \int_{y=0}^t f_{Y_1}(t - y) f_{Y_2}(y) \, dy = \lambda^2 \int_{y=0}^t \frac{e^{-\lambda(1/(t-y) + 1/y)}}{(y(t-y))^2} \, dy.$$
Needless to say, even the case $\lambda = 1$ is intractable.

Moreover, the mean is infinite.  I suspect the absence of literature on the topic may be due to these properties--no closed form and no first moment or higher.  Moreover, what kind of random process is modeled by such a statistic?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm doing research at a neuroscience laboratory and certain measures of neural plasticity using transcranial magnetic stimulation involve sums of the inverse of exponentially distributed random variables.

Comment: @lafinur Interesting, thanks for the context.  The unboundedness of a first moment would seem to suggest such a measure would not be well-behaved with respect to the use of sample statistics to perform parameter estimation or statistical inference.  Model assumptions for most statistical procedures require consistency of the estimator, which does not seem to be satisfied here.

Comment: I appreciate the insight, as cleary you are more knowledgable than I on this regard. In fact, we did find that the measure in question, which involves the sum of inverse exponential random variables, is pretty much useless in classical statistical inference. Notwithstanding, it had great predictive power in predicting certain clinical conditions when training a machine learning model over it. The research I'm working on goes a little bit about that. Feel free to continue this conversation in a private chat, I'm curious on what you think. Thanks.